# Rewrite for loop / speed up code

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I've written a piece of code. And I'm sure it can be implemented in a much faster way. Does someone has some pointers. I know that nested for loops are not very pythonic.

The code basically calculates KLD divergence between documents in a doc_topic matrix using a changing window size.

```
def calculate(dataframe):
dates = []
novelty = []
transience = []
resonance = []
time_frame = []
for w in range(1, 500, 1):
    print(w)
    for i in range(w, doc_topic.shape[0] - w ):
        time_frame.append(w)
        avg_transience = 0
        avg_novelty = 0
        dates.append(dataframe.iloc[i]['date'])
        novelties = []
        transiences = []
        for d in range(1, w+1):
            novelties.append(KLD(doc_topic[i], doc_topic[i-d]))
            transiences.append(KLD(doc_topic[i], doc_topic[i+d]))
        avg_novelty = 1/w * np.sum(novelties)
        avg_transience = 1/w * np.sum(transiences)
        transience.append(avg_transience)
        novelty.append(avg_novelty)
        resonance = [a - b for a, b in zip(novelty, transience)]
        resonance = np.array(resonance)
df_kld = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(transience, novelty, resonance)),
          columns=['transience','novelty', 'resonance'])
df_kld['time_frame'] = time_frame
df_kld['dates'] = dates
df_kld.to_pickle('df_kld_final.pkl')
return df_kld
```

Comment: Can you post the input and expected output?

Comment: You overwrite the `resonance` array in each iteration of the inner loop. Is this intended behaviour?

Comment: If your code works (which might actually not be the case, cf other comments) and you're asking for improvments then the right place is codereview, not SO.

Comment: @twolffpiggott yes it should be outdented one step which speeds it up considerably. Thanks for spotting that (results stay some luckily)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thanks, I didn't know about that one I'll check that one out and remove this question.